# Change integration variable from scalar to matrix

Tags: integration, matrices, matrix-calculus, substitution

Suppose $c$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{A}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $g(.)$ is some real-valued function. Define $\mathbf{B} = c \, \mathbf{A}$.

In this integral,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(c) \; det(c \, \mathbf{A}) \; dc = \int ? d\mathbf{B},
$$

how do I change the integration variable to $\mathbf{B}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $A\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n},\,$ then
$$\eqalign{
\det(cA) &= c^n\det(A) \\
B &= Ac \implies AB = BA\\
A^{-1}B &= Ic \;\implies A^{-1}dB = I\,dc \\
{\rm Tr}(I) &= n \\
f(x) &= x^ng(x) \\
}$$
Using this, the integration variable can be changed.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal J}  &= \int \det(A)\,f(c)\,dc \\
{\cal J}I &= \int \det(A)\,f(A^{-1}B)\,A^{-1}dB \\
{\cal J}I &= \int  \det(A)\,A^{-1}f(A^{-1}B)\,dB \\
{\cal J}\;{\rm Tr}(I) 
 &= {\rm Tr}\left(\int\det(A)\,A^{-1}f(A^{-1}B)\,dB\right) \\
{\cal J} 
 &= \frac{1}{n}\;{\rm Tr}\left(\int\det(A)\,A^{-1}f(A^{-1}B)\,dB\right) \\
 &= \int G:dB \\
}$$
where
$G$ is the gradient of ${\cal J}$ with respect to $B$
$$\eqalign{
G &= \frac{\partial{\cal J}}{\partial B} 
  \;=\; \frac{1}{n}\,\det(A)\,A^{-1}f(A^{-1}B) \\
}$$
and
the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(AB^T)$$
When both matrices are symmetric, this can be simplified to
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(AB)$$

Comment: Can you help me understand the $f(A^{-1} B)$ part. $g(x)$ is a scalar valued function, so how do I think about $f(x) = x^n g(x)$, with $x=A^{-1} B=Ic$?

Comment: For any scalar valued function like f$(x)$, substituting $Ix$ as the argument yields $f(Ix) = I\,f(x)$. This seperabilty property does **not** hold for other matrices, i.e.  $\,f(Ax) \ne A\,f(x)$